# How to add "The Window Menu panel plugin" shortcut?

Tags: xfce

How to add shortcut to activate "The Window Menu panel plugin"?

It would be very cool and usable to be able to activate this applet with keyboard, and no mouse needed.

I use xfce 4.10, ubuntu 12.10

**Found some info here:**

http://promberger.info/linux/2007/10/11/xfce-show-menu-and-windowlist-using-keyboard-shortcut/

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1888070.html

Shortcut command looks like this:

```
xfdesktop --windowlist
```

And how can i add this custom shortcut to xfce keyboard shortcuts, to activate applet with expanded Windows list (now they are not expanded, need to expand by hand) where he plased on Panel?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late reply, but it's still valid at Xfce 4.10 (the current stable release).
All you need to do is open Settings > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts and click the Add button at the bottom. In the command line (input field), enter "xfdesktop --windowlist" (without the quotes) and click OK. You will be prompted to choose a shortcut key. Perhaps +w (for Windows) might be a reasonable choice, if you're not using it for anything else.

Comment: Hi, that work, but popped out window shows list of all virtual windows, and i must use mouse to expand every window to see running programms in every. So that solution isnt 100% perfect. Thanx!